# What is $\limsup_n \mid \sin(n\theta) \mid^{1/n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

What is $\limsup_n \mid \sin(n\theta) \mid^{1/n}$ ? where $\theta$ is any real number except integer multiples of $\pi$.

I suspect the answer is $1$ but am not so sure.

In fact let $u_n=i(3+4i)^n-i(3-4i)^n$ and I hope to calculate the $\limsup _n \mid u_n \mid ^{1/n}$.

I suspect that the value is $5$, but cannot prove rigorously. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Surely your guess is false when $\theta =\pi$

Comment: Oh, I will edit it to exclude such situations.

Comment: Looking at the power series $\sum u_n z^{n}$ and finding its radius of convergence may help.

Comment: Stil there appear oscillating $sin(n\theta)$ terms.

Comment: It appears that you are asking two distinct questions here (one about $\limsup |\sin(n\theta)^{1/n}|$, and one about $\limsup |i ((3+41)^n - (3-4i)^n)|$).  Can you please edit your question to focus on only one question?

Comment: The key part of the second question is the first question. They are closed related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove that the limsup is 1 by showing  that for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$ $\exists n_k>k$ with $ |\sin (n_k\theta)|>0.5$. Now take the increasing series $(n_k)_{k=1}^{\infty},$ with $n_k$ beeing the smallest integer $\geq k$ such that $ |\sin (n_k\theta)|>0.5.$

It now follows that $$ 1\geq \lim_{k\to\infty}|\sin (n_k\theta)|^{1/n_k}\geq \lim_{k\to\infty} 0.5^{1/n_k}=1$$
Therefore also $\limsup |\sin (n\theta)|^{1/n}=1$